# For an electron, how does QED maintain a constant rest mass and remove its classical radius from CEM?

Tags: electrons, field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, classical-electrodynamics

From [classical electromagnetism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electromagnetism), the [classical radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classical_electron_radius) of the electron is calculated to be

$$r_\text{e} = \frac{1}{4\pi\varepsilon_0}\frac{e^2}{m_{\text{e}} c^2} = 2.817 940 3227(19) \times 10^{-15} \text{ m}$$

Secondly, its rest mass is predicted to change when placed in a non-constant electric field as parts are accelerated differently to one another in its rest frame. [QED](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics) on the other hand treats the electron as a point particle with a constant rest mass which so far have been increasingly confirmed experimentally.

*What additional physical processes, if any, come into play within QED to maintain the constant rest mass and point-like properties of the electron compared to within CEM?*

Comment: Is the classical radius really *calculated*?  I thought it was just a convenient combination of constants without that interpretation.

Comment: @QuantumDot you can model an electron as a charged sphere of radius $r_e$ and calculate the work done in constructing it by moving a continuous charge distribution from infinity.

Comment: The classical radius of electron is a fictitious concept based on the idea of mass of electron being entirely electromagnetic. That idea made some sense in pre-relativistic theory where in addition to matter, only EM field  was able  to carry momentum, not constraint force field keeping the charge together. Then, relativity was discovered -- but in any relativistic theory non-EM forces should also carry momentum, according to relativity, contribute to its mass. So models of distributed electron charge  won't in general give radius that is equal to classical electron radius.

Comment: Such models of distributed electrons are indefinite due to infinity of possible ways of how the charged parts interact non-electromagnetically with each other. So there was not much progress in this direction in classical theory. On the other hand, modern applications of classical EM theory (motion of charged particles in media and in EM fields) work successfully with the concept of point electron where observed charge and mass are not related in any way. No additional process is needed to be introduced to keep the electron as a point of constant mass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is solved, in a way, by separating the "bare mass" that appears in the Lagrangian from the "physical mass" that we observe in experiments. The bare mass diverges under renormalization, irrespective of concerns about the energy content of the electric field around a point-like electron. A standard response to this is that the Lagrangian parameters aren't physically observable, anyway, they're just computational tools.

You can look at this problem from another point of view. individual electrons are excitations in a Fermionic field, usually one that obeys the Dirac equation in the appropriate limit. The electric field produced by a point-like excitation in that field has a divergent energy content in the associated electric field, but so what? That just means that point-like excitations aren't physically realizabile in that field and must, therefore, be computational tools, kind of like the virtual paths used when extremizing the action to get the equations of motion in classical physics.

Comment: So what? It can't _be_ a point-like excitation in that field.

Comment: This makes sense, although I was hoping that virtual particles around the electron might play a part in this.

Comment: @JohnMcVirgo Nope. The virtual particals behave, in some approximations, like a polarizable medium. Look at the electric field generated by a charge embedded in a polarizable medium: the medium *screens* the charge, making the long range apparent charge smaller, in magnitude, than the unscreened version. Pair product and QFT makes the problem of point-like charges worse, not better.

Comment: This interesting article on [SUSY](https://www.forbes.com/sites/startswithabang/2019/02/12/why-supersymmetry-may-be-the-greatest-failed-prediction-in-particle-physics-history/#20db044869e6) claims that virtual particles do play a part in making the electron point-like.